# How to display system fonts in a UITableView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how can I create an array of the system fonts ? - the ones that are available in the storyboard.

What I am trying to do is have a `TableView` displaying all the fonts, I know how to display an array in a `UITableView` but unsure how to create the array of system fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your array like :

```
var arrayOfFonts: [AnyObject] = UIFont.familyNames()
```

Comment: When I display the array in a tableView would I just do this to display the text ?        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfFonts[indexPath.row]

Comment: cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOfFonts[indexPath.row].stringValue

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C:
     NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];

Swift: 
UIFont.familyNames(); //It returns an array of Strings.

Comment: Could you do that in swift please ?